# How to decode Data (ie block state) bytes in Minecraft schematic (nbt) file?

Tags: javascript, minecraft, decoding

I am parsing a `schematic file` with the [following structure](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Schematic_file_format)

> The **.schematic file format** was created by the community to store sections of a Minecraft world for use with third-party programs. Schematics are in [NBT format](https://wiki.vg/NBT)
>
> The [Named Binary Tag (NBT) file format](https://wiki.vg/NBT) is an extremely simple structured binary format used by the Minecraft game for a variety of things

Block [`Data Value`s](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Data_values) define parts of the terrain in Minecraft.

I retrieving [the `block data`](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Block_states) of every Minecraft Block, and need to figure out how to decode these bytes. This is [an example for the `Stairs` Minecraft Block](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Stairs#Block_data)

For example [the stairs block data](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Stairs#Block_data) includes:

[image]

I can use [nbt-js](https://github.com/sjmulder/nbt-js) to parse the entire schematic file, which enables me to access the block data like this:

```
var b = schem.value.Data.value[index];
```

I decode the **Stairs Block Data** bits data with the following code

```
var facing = b & 0x03;
var half = (b >> 2) & 0x01;
var shape = (b >> 3) & 0x03;
```

These configuration values are essential to determine how the stair block should be rendered.  For example, I use the facing value to rotate the block:

```
block.rotateX(facing);
```

However, the bits are interpreted differently for every block type, and this isn't defined anywhere that I can find.

Comment: can you update your question with a clear reproducible or easy to understand example?

Comment: Done, see edit2.

Comment: I refactored your question, but it is still not clear: 1) `schem.value.Data.value[index];` what is the value of the `b` variable and what is the value of `schem` etc... maybe you want to create a [`fiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/) and stub the values so that we can quickly recreate your scenario. 2) what is the output of `facing = data & 0x03;` and the rest of the code. Try to create some sort of fiddle or explain clearly the code.

Comment: @lancew Have you already checked out https://www.npmjs.com/package/mc-schematic which builds upon https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-data ? Looks pretty promising to me,

Comment: @FabrizioBertoglio thank you, I can see that its much easier to read now.  I edited further to retain the original purpose.

Comment: @Fitzi Thank you for your help.  I did look through those projects, and just spent some more time going through them.  From what I can tell, they don't actually decode the data bits, just provide access to them.  Its a lot to look through though, so I could have missed it.

Comment: *Questions asking us to [recommend or find a tool, software library are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.* I suggest you to update your answer so that the problem is very clear. I am happy to reverse all my edits, but your question went from 4 to 10 upvotes so probably it is better off. The current question is on how to decode one block, you never included in your question the logic to decode multiple blocks.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant for others to solve your problem, but to receive assistance and finding a collective solution.

Comment: I definitely asked for a solution to decode ALL blocks in the original question.  I am fine with the current edits though.  My hope was that someone who has done this before would share their solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## There does not exist a mapping that works for all blocks

<sub>And you'll just have to deal with it</sub>

This is *the entire reason why* 1.13 and The Flattening is removing metadata entirely resulting in all blockstates encoded as strings when serialized (NBT is a serialized data format and the one used for just about everything before reaching the Anvil format). At runtime these states are parsed and turned into true `Object` instances, obviating the need for magic values.

So you won't have to work out that `facing = b & 0x03;` you'll instead get `{"facing":"east"}`

Unfortunately, if you're working below 1.13, you will have to deal with metadata magic values and there is no solution unless you have runtime access to the game and can call `getStateFromMeta()` (1.10 through 1.12; unsure where 1.8 and 1.9 sit, as I never modded for those versions).

Comment: Wait, so for any schematic saved from 1.13 I won’t have to deal with the block state bit decoding?  Are the standard schematic plugins currently able to save schematics from 1.13?

Comment: I don't know if any schematic plugins are available for 1.13 or if the schematic file format has been updated to reflect, but *if one is available* then it would have to support the new BlockState format (as metadata is 100% gone).

Comment: Thank you.  Unless anyone proves you wrong in the time limit, this answer will get the bounty.